# How to sort products by a taxon property in Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

The Spree (2.3.4) application I've inherited has a taxonomy named "Makers" with multiple taxons associated to it by 'taxonomy_id'. I have been tasked with sorting products by the taxon's 'name' property, something like

```
Spree::Product.order('taxon.name DESC')
```

I think I need to do an `includes` on the Products table, but I'm not sure how to write that correctly.

How do I include the correct taxonomy in order to sort by a property of its taxons? Thanks.

Comment: Is the taxon name present on product page or table?

Comment: @CaffeineCoder 'name' is a field on the 'spree_taxons' table. It's not present in any of the pages.

Comment: Then you can override the particular controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out:

```
Spree::Product.includes(:taxons).where(spree_taxons: {taxonomy_id: Spree::Taxonomy.find_by(name: 'Makers').id}).order("spree_taxons.name desc")
```

I didn't know that you could use `.where()` like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly override this [controller](https://github.com/spree/spree/blob/2-4-stable/backend/app/controllers/spree/admin/taxons_controller.rb) in your local , and change the attribute you want to sort by . Only pick the method you want to use , instead of picking up the whole controller code . Let me know if i can help you more .

Note - Be sure , the path you override the controller is exactly the same as in github .

Comment: I don't think I follow. The client wants this sorting method applied only after selecting an option from a dropdown menu. It's currently sorted by price via `products.includes([master: :prices]).order("spree_prices.amount #{ sort_order }")` and he wants me to change that to sorting by the maker's name.

Comment: Can you see the related code in your local application ?

Comment: What do you mean by 'related'? I don't see that controller in the local source code.

Comment: Yes , that's why i said you need to override . This will involve making a same file as shown in the github repo , where you will be taking the related code from github and change the search attributes , that's how spree will pick up changes from your application . Until then it will follow the same default search it does

Comment: I guess I'm just not understanding how overriding that controller that will change `products.includes([master: :prices]).order("spree_prices.amount #{ sort_order }")` to sorting by maker name. This sorting should happen on many different pages after a user selects a sorting method from a dropdown list.

Comment: You need to find out if the action being called is the same in other pages too , if it's the same then overriding only one controller would do or else you will have to override all the different controllers where this search happens .

Comment: This happens in a model. The model method is called from all the controllers where products are listed. I just need to change the one line for it to be applied throughout the app

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80255/discussion-between-caffeine-coder-and-aperture).